# Is it possible to ouput c#'s Console.writeline to Jenkins job's console logs?

Tags: c#, shell, unit-testing, jenkins, output

I'm running a Jenkins server as a windows service package.

Everything works fine except when I try to run a C# project (.exe) using cmd.exe as a shell command line. It runs properly, but I'd like to be able to see everything that the .exe output (Console.writeline) directly into the Job's console output.

Can somebody point me out how to do this? I tried putting it in a batch file, but even ECHO commands aren't printed out.

At my job, our Jenkins does print out stuff but we are using cmake over there... Could it be the reason?

Thanks